# Alternative to mini.iso for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: iso

I've discovered that Ubuntu no longer provides the mini.iso image for 22.04.

For my project's needs I'm looking for an image that:

- Is of 22.04
- Is provided by Ubuntu/Canonical (for trust reasons)
- Supports serial consoles (like mini.iso)
- Has as little in it as possible (not as critical).

Is there any option for me around? I looked quite a bit and couldn't find anything.

I'd really rather not have to build an image from scratch if I don't have to.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: "Is provided by Ubuntu/Canonical (for trust reasons)"  Small issue: the mini.iso has and never was a official release by canonical ;-) The go-to minimal install is Damn Small Linux (not an Ubuntu though).  The only way to get to 22.04 is by using the 20.04 mini.iso and upgrade. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264128/how-to-do-a-minimal-install-of-20-04 The minimal version of Ubuntu as of 22.04 is the server version. Don't get any smaller.

Comment: There is an alternative way to get Ubuntu Server: via a compressed image file. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451590/is-there-a-version-of-ubuntu-which-boots-to-command-line-without-needing-to-inst/1451611#1451611) and links from it. This is particularly useful if you want a portable system (in a USB pendrive or USB-connected SSD). -- Otherwise, to install into an internal drive, the Ubuntu Server iso files with an installer provide more options during the installation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option similar to the mini.iso for Ubuntu 22.04.  The new "live server" installer (*subiquity*) should meet your requirements except for "Has as little in it as possible".

If you love the mini.iso ([you are not alone](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291931/376778)) and want to hear there is hope for the future then there is a [Publishing netboot artifacts spec](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/spec-publishing-netboot-artifacts/28256) to create *subiquity* netboot artifacts, possibly including a "micro.iso".  The thread has not had much activity.

If you dig around enough there are some 3rd party projects out there.  For instance, this [ubuntu-server-netboot](https://github.com/dannf/ubuntu-server-netboot) project tries to recreate the netboot.tar.gz file that was created along with the mini.iso for minimal installs.  I have no idea if it works.

In general, the [Ubuntu Server Discourse section](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/search?q=mini.iso%20category%3A17) has the most information about the mini.iso removal.  I would characterize this mostly as end users asking for the return of mini.iso and developers saying it should not have been used to begin with.  Some samples.

- [Mini.iso possible anymore?](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mini-iso-possible-anymore/28383) thread with no replies
- [A user created poll](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/poll-about-possible-netboot-mini-iso-revival-in-future-ubuntu-releases/19457) thread that did not have any developer support.
- [Netbooting the live server installer](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510/1) thread contains a number of comments about mini.iso, including

> The mini.iso has in fact never been a “supported” install method for Ubuntu, and is not part of the test matrix for Ubuntu releases. And there will not be an equivalent mini.iso image for use with subiquity.

> The mini.iso has also never been a supported install method. It is a side effect of the d-i build process which is not QAed, has known limitations, and is not promoted for download by the Ubuntu website or the Ubuntu cdimage website. It is frequently used to create unsupported, and unsupportable, installations that are missing key Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I have bad news for you. The netboot (mini.iso) images are [no longer created](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot/jammy/) by Ubuntu. Even the [most recent (20.04) image](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/) was referred to as "legacy."

The closest replacement would be the [ubuntu-server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) images.

Answer (score 0):

[Netboot.xyz](https://netboot.xyz/downloads/) fits the bill IMO

With the notable exception of RAM usage, mini.iso could be installed on 256MB RAM, while Netboot.xyz needs [>=3GB RAM](https://github.com/netbootxyz/netboot.xyz/issues/1128) to run the installation, while the netboot.iso itself is <3MB in size